# Should MySQL Charset be the same as my php files charset?

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

I have PHP files with charset UTF-8. Do I have to use the same charset for my MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not obligatory that they are the same, It would be best practice to do so. This, to avoid any UTF8 problems while storing data from PHP into your database, I would advise placing everything in the same UTF-8 charset. It will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In your php page use charset UTF-8   and when you create your database and table set collection to utf8_general_ci from dropdown ... it will support all language and save directly to database  as you send from you php page